# How to add specific configuration to a Maven plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, protocol-buffers

In my pom.xml I configure a plugin to convert certain Protobuf files to Java class files. It looks like this:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.igor-petruk.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <executions>
                 <execution>
                         <goals>
                                 <goal>run</goal>
                         </goals>
                 </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
              <protocCommand>${basedir}/protoc/bin/protoc</protocCommand>
              <inputDirectories>
                    <inputDirectory>proto</inputDirectory>
              </inputDirectories>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Out of this Maven generates the `.classpath` file with the following entry:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="target/generated-sources/protobuf">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

What I would now like Maven to do is to add an additional "attribute" entry to that classpath entry so that the entry looks like this:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="target/generated-sources/protobuf">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="ignore_optional_problems" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Like that I won't get warnings from that part of the code.

At the moment I just don't know how to do that. Which files or other settings do I have to edit? Where in Eclipse can I do that?
But this is more or less a general question as to how Maven can be modified to include customized entries, because we have some more spots where we would want to add custom things in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Login and vote for this Feature-Request:](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388541)

There already is a patch, improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse configuration in your example is produced by [m2eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)'s project configuratior and I'm quite certain it doesn't support such feature right now. Though you can try to submit an enhancement request. See http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/support/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if is possible using maven. You will have to call ant plugin from maven. Add the custom logic to add the extra line in Ant task.

Add the ant plugin below your plugin to ensure that ant plugin gets called after your plugin in same phase. Make sure ant plugin has the same phase as your plugin.

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase><!--the same phase as protobuf-maven-plugin phase--></phase>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>

            <!--
              Add ant xmltask or ant other task to add your line to file
            -->

          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```